# SASS/Compass / Structure / Compile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

So last resort coming here hopefully someone can lend a hand.

I'm building a project in SASS-Bootstrap3

all my sites are created (40 of them)

I want all the sites to run off the same `bootstrap-sass.scss` file:
this file mentioned above has parts of bootstrap imported into it `@import` on multiple files _`forms.scss` for example.

Now my 40 sites 
are slightly different but follow same bootstrap structure.

so in each sites `/assets/scss/` folder they have 
variables.scss
overrides.scss

what I want to do is automatically compile the globally shared (bootstrap-scss) with the variables and overrides of each site for each site.

so the output would be in each sites `/assets/css/`
folder.

this to me seems like a pretty sensible way to do things especially if I can run it all from a batch every time I do a big update on the main `bootstrap-sass.scss`

so my question is how do I combine multiple `.scss` files from different directories.

Kind regards,
Ant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would navigate to them from the file you're working in.

Let's say the setup is:

```
/super-site
  /master
    /assets
      /scss
        _bootstrap-sass.scss
  /site-1
    /assets
      /scss
        _variables.scss
        _overrides.scss
        site-1.scss
  /site-2
    /assets
      /scss
        _variables.scss
        _overrides.scss
        site-2.scss
```

This would be your `site-1.scss` file.

```
@import "variables";
@import "overrides";
@import "../../master/assets/scss/bootstrap-sass";
```

However, if you're running Sass from the command line you can set load paths wtih `-I`.

```
cd super-site
sass -I super-site/master/assets/scss --watch site-1/assets/scss:site-1/assets/scss site-2/assets/scss:site-2/assets/scss
```

Then you can do just do

```
@import "variables";
@import "overrides";
@import "bootstrap-sass";
```

without going through all the `../` action. I'm sure there's a clever way to not have to do site-1..site-40 with some sweet command line action but I'm not super familiar with it.

Comment: thanks so much for your reply Bill didnt think anyone was going to ;)

So what you are saying kind of makes sense.

Comment: So sorry and again, so your structure makes ALOT more sense now I wasnt aware you could import from outer directories like that

Comment: Yup! You're welcome. Just like CSS. You ever have to do `background-image: url("../images/logo.png");` or anything? Same idea.

Comment: agreed! haha i dont know how i overlooked this, so when i do a compass watch on Site-2.scss then everything such as variables.scss / overrides.scss / bootstrap.scss and all of its children will be watched. correct?

Comment: I think you would need to watch the entire directory and not just the file to detect if an `@import`ed file changes. I may be wrong. I'd set up a test, try it and see.